# Sending an jquery AJAX GET request with Python request library

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, request

I have a website I need to scrape and it is using jquery AJAX function to get information from the server. I have been investigating the code for a while and I successfully get the response from server using:

```
data = {'part_number':'1234'}
r = $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'ajaxurl',
        data : data
    })
```

Note that this is done via js console so I am alreadt logged in. When I try to do it in python I need to login first of course:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0','Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
payload = {'username':'me','password':'1234'}
link = 'login url'
session = requests.Session()
resp = session.get(link,headers=headers)
cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies))
resp = session.post(link,headers=headers,data=payload,cookies =cookies)

#until here sucesss!"############

url = "ajaxurl"
my_params={'part_number':'1234'}
r = session.get( url = url, data = my_params, cookies =cookies,headers =headers )
```

The post request for login goes well but for the GET response I receive BAD REQUEST 400. I cannot figure out how to format my request. I don't know what ajax does to my request. Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Ok I got something else. When I add                                                         'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' the status code of the response changes to 500 Internal Server Error with the content : ''SOAP request failed with fault code "1543" and fault string "An error occurred while processing diagram node "Output 2". Attempting to convert data with a picture clause into a string failed. Source field, invalid source value and picture clause: Root.PW00118O.DOCDATA.PART-FOLDER-ISSUE-PUB,   , 9(2)."'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it!
I added `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` to headers and did:

```
pn = '1234'
r = requests.get(ajaxurl + '?part_number=' + pn, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Did not understand why though :(

Comment: It tells the server you're requesting the content via a XMLHttpRequest, e.g. AJAX.

Comment: A bit late, but, servers can very easily filter requests that are not AJAX generated (request type: xhr). I guess that's why you got a 400 response.

Answer (score 0):

**BAD REQUEST 400** means that the server was unable to understand or process your request (the data you sent via AJAX).

Since you're using `GET` method in AJAX, I would give a try to traditional url with query string:

```
var request = 'part_number=1234';
$.get('http://your.website/your_server_file?'+request, function(data){
    // handle the server response (data) here ...
});
```

Comment: Well the ajax request with jquery is successful. The question is how to do it using python namely emulating it.