# Python requests lib can't replicate AJAX

Tags: python, ajax

I'm trying to replicate this request with the `requests` module:

```
$.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/Game/PlaceLauncher.ashx",
            data: {
                request: "RequestGame",
                placeId: n,
                isPartyLeader: t,
                gender: i
            },
            crossDomain: !0,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: !0
            }
        })
```

How would I do `crossDomain` and `xhrFields`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending an jquery AJAX GET request with Python request library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610376/sending-an-jquery-ajax-get-request-with-python-request-library)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking question is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried, and any error messages.