# Dealing with xhr requests in Python HTML Scraping

Tags: python, html, ajax, web-scraping

I need to scrape the entire HTML from journal_url, which for the purpose of this example will be http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1467-6281/issues . I have followed the requests examples displayed on a few questions on this site, but I am not getting the correct HTML returned with either the .text or .json() methods for requests.get. My goal is to display the whole HTML including the ordered list underneath each year and volume pull-down.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import http.cookiejar
for i in range(0,len(df)):
         journal_name = df.loc[i,"Journal Full Title"]
         journal_url = df.loc[i,"URL"]+"/issues"
         access_start = df.loc[i,"Content Start Date"]
         access_end = df.loc[i,"Content End Date"]
         #cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
         #opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

         headers = {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
               "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"}

         r = requests.get(journal_url, headers=headers)

         response = r.text
         print(response)
```

Comment: Why do you have `"X-Requested-With"` in `headers`?

Comment: From my understanding, this states we want the content via an XML request (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610376/sending-an-jquery-ajax-get-request-with-python-request-library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ultimate goal is to parse the content you mentioned above from that page, then here it is:

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_link = "http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com" ; main_link = "http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/(ISSN)1467-6281/issues"

def abacus_scraper(main_link):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(main_link).text, "html.parser")
    for titles in soup.select("a.issuesInYear"):
        title = titles.select("span")[0].text
        title_link = titles.get("href")
        main_content(title, title_link)

def main_content(item, link):
    broth = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_link + link).text, "html.parser")
    elems = [issue.text for issue in broth.select("div.issue a")]
    print(item, elems)

abacus_scraper(main_link)
```

Comment: I apolagize for the delayed response, but this doesn'

Comment: "This doesn't" doesn't always clarify things. you meant, the data you are not after, right?

Comment: Sorry, that was an accidental post. This should get me to what I need. Thanks!